# How to make tabbar navigate between webpages with one wkwebview?

Tags: ios, swift3, navigation, wkwebview, tabbar

I use `wkwebview` to render the web page, I have three web pages. I want to use tabbar to navigate between these three pages. I feel each `wkwebview` a page may take too much resource.

So I just want to use only one `wkwebview` to load the three-page. when touching the tab, the webpage page loaded. i.e. when tab1 clicked, the page1 loaded, tab2 clicked, the page2 loaded, same for tab3 and page3. Now I can just load a page with `wkwebview`, I'm new to ios.

if tabbar cannot implement this, what should I do?

Comment: i think you will have to provide the 3 urls for this and using one webview without going back and forth its not so much possible.

Comment: @AliFarhan back or forth is navigate in the history. For each page has inner links, so navigating may not works with three different page.

Comment: @AliFarhan I implemented this in android. With a tabbar, I can navigate amone three different pages. and with back button, I can navigate in the history. I just want to implement this in ios. But find it's not easy for me, supposint I'm new to IOS programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to something like then add `UITabbar` with 3 tabitem inside your `ViewController` and then set delegate of it with your `ViewController`. Now implement `didSelect item` method of `UITabbar` and load the url according the tab.

```
func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    switch item.title! {
    case "First":
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url1))
    case "Second":
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url2))
    default:
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url3))
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to ask question if you don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can override method `handleNavBackButton()` to get callback on back button.

```
override func handleNavBackButton() {
  if webViewData.canGoBack {
    webViewData.goBack()
  } else {
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  }
}
```

Please let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Thank you, I mean when I touch tab1 the page1 loaded, tab2 the page2 loaded, not back or forward the history.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using two different scenes, you need to use combination of UIViewController + UIToolbar. Add your two UIBarButtonItem(s) to your toolbar. Set their action to the desired url and you are done.